# Hibernate is not generating proper sql query for Hibernate Named Query in ( hbm file ) mapping file

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have a hibernate named query defined in hbm file.

```
<query name="AddressBook.find_by_user_id_and_type_lease_time">
    <![CDATA[ FROM AddressBook addressBook 
        WHERE addressBook.mightyUser.userId = ? 
        and addressBook.typeId = ? 
        and (addressBook.lockOwner is null
        or (addressBook.lockOwner is not null 
        and (sysdate - addressBook.lockLeaseDate) > ?))]]>
</query>
```

Upon executing this query through hibernate Query interface, found that the generated query is not proper. Here '(' is ignored/chopped from the query.

```
 2016-01-13 12:26:44.327 475eb4d0 D 00000000000000000000000000000000    02a5:select addressboo0_.ADDRESS_BOOK_ID as ADDRESS1_37_, addressboo0_.VERSION as VERSION37_, addressboo0_.ADDRESS_BOOK_NAME as ADDRESS3_37_, addressboo0_.UPDATED_TIME as UPDATED4_37_, addressboo0_.CREATED_DT as CREATED5_37_, addressboo0_.TYPE_ID as TYPE6_37_, addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER as LOCK7_37_, addressboo0_.DEDUPE_DATE as DEDUPE8_37_, addressboo0_.LOCK_LEASE_DATE as LOCK9_37_, addressboo0_.ACCOUNT_NAME as ACCOUNT10_37_, addressboo0_.USER_ID as USER11_37_ from R4GDEV02_MBW.ADDRESSBOOK addressboo0_ where addressboo0_.USER_ID=? and addressboo0_.TYPE_ID=? and (addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER is null or 
***(addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER is not null) and sysdate-addressboo0_.LOCK_LEASE_DATE>?)***
```

Please suggest/advice

Comment: Because of hibernate is removing `(` from the required places the actual logic changing, here is generated query without `(`  `and (addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER is null or (addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER is not null) and sysdate-addressboo0_.LOCK_LEASE_DATE>?)`   But required query is  `and (addressBook.lockOwner is null
        or (addressBook.lockOwner is not null 
        and (sysdate - addressBook.lockLeaseDate) > ?))`  Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL query is correct because of `and` has  higher priority than `or`. So you don't need  brackets in 
`(addressBook.lockOwner is not null and (sysdate - addressBook.lockLeaseDate) > ?)`

**Update**

```
(addressBook.lockOwner is null or 
    (addressBook.lockOwner is not null and (sysdate - addressBook.lockLeaseDate) > ?))
```

means

```
(A + (B * C))
```

and

```
(addressBook.lockOwner is null or 
    (addressBook.lockOwner is not null) and sysdate - addressBook.lockLeaseDate > ?)
```

means

```
(A + B * C)
```

It is the same

```
(A + (B * C)) = (A + B * C)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick suggestion, But if you see the query escaping `(` is changing the actual logic, this is generated logic ` (addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER is not null) and sysdate-addressboo0_.LOCK_LEASE_DATE>)` but actually required is (addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER is null or (addressboo0_.LOCK_OWNER is not null and (sysdate-addressboo0_.LOCK_LEASE_DATE)>?) )